# Unable to get my RefinableString01 showing inside our PnP Modern search V4 web part's Search filter web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, crawled-property, refiner, pnp-search-webparts

We have a list column of type Choice (inside the built-in SitePages library) which allow multiple selection named Category, as follow:-

[image]

and inside the tenant search schema >> i mapped the related crawl property with the RefinableString01 managed property, as follow:-

[image]

I issued an index for the SitePages library and for the whole site 2 days ago >> but when i edit the PnP Search Filter webpart (we are using this App https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search)>> the RefinableString01 will not be shown inside the Filter Field drop down, as follow:-

[image]

nor inside the selected properties list inside the search web part:-

[image]

any advice ? what i can do to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can freely type the managed property name in the search box and then press Enter.

The entered property will be added to the list automatically.